# Making a CGImage from a CMSampleBuffer in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, avfoundation, core-image

Below is a summary of all the relevant parts from my attempted solutions.

#### Attempt #1

```
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(buffer, 0)

let ctx = CIContext()

let ciImage = CIImage(CVPixelBuffer: buffer)

let cgImage = ctx.createCGImage(ciImage, fromRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, CGFloat(size.width), CGFloat(size.height)))

CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(buffer, 0)
```

#### Attempt #2

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(CGFloat(size.width), CGFloat(size.height)))

let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
let contextData = CGBitmapContextGetData(context)
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(buffer, 0)
let bufferData = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(buffer)
let bufferSize = CVPixelBufferGetDataSize(buffer)
memcpy(contextData, bufferData, bufferSize)
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(buffer, 0)
let cgImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext().CGImage

UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

#### Attempt #3

```
let bufferAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(buffer)

let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(buffer)

let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

let provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(nil, bufferAddress, bytesPerRow * size.height, nil)

let cgImage = CGImageCreate(size.width, size.height, 8, 32, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo, provider, nil, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!